# TFIM with ComponentSpace library?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, federated-identity, tivoli-identity-manager, component-space

I am trying to user Tivoli Federated Identity Manager 6.2 as identity provider and an application that have SAML 2.0 support using ComponentSpace library.

Will that application be able to support TFIM or not? And if it's supported then can anyone provide any instruction or information ore documentation related to use of these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, interoperability with TFIM is supported. You should ask for the SAML metadata from the partner provider using TFIM. The SAML metadata includes information such as the URLs used for SSO, the X.509 certificate used for signature verification, and the partner's entity ID.

You can use the ImportMetadata utility to import the TFIM SAML metadata and have your local SAML configuration (ie saml.config) updated with this information.

The partner provider will most likely want your SAML metadata so they can update the TFIM configuration/

You can use the ExportMetadata utility to export the local SAML configuration (ie saml.config) to a SAML metadata file that may be supplied to the partner provider.

The ImportMetadata and ExportMetadata projects may be found under the Examples/Metadata folder.